# How to bind command correctly in my custom control WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, selecteditem, relaycommand

Here's my control:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <Border BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="DarkGray">
            <Grid Height="30">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <CheckBox Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"  Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto"/>

                <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.UpCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
                                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="1" ToolTip="Up" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}">
                    <Image Source="/Resources/Icons/sort_up.png"/>
                </Button>

                <Button 
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.DownCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
                        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="1" ToolTip="Down" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}">
                    <Image Source="/Resources/Icons/sort_down.png"/>
                </Button>

            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And the code in the View Model includes this:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Moves item up in the custom list
    /// </summary>
    private void UpCommandExecuted()
    {
        if (SelectedItem != null)
        {
            StoredProc Proc = SelectedItem;
            int oldLocation = TheList.IndexOf(SelectedItem);
            if (oldLocation > 0)
            {
                if (SelectedItem.IsChecked || (TheList[oldLocation - 1].IsChecked == SelectedItem.IsChecked))
                {
                    TheList.RemoveAt(oldLocation);
                    TheList.Insert(oldLocation - 1, Proc);
                    SelectedItem = Proc;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I also have a `SelectedItem` property in VM that is a `StoredProcedure` (type I made up). This is working, but clicking any of the listbox's item "Up" button causes the SELECTEDITEM to be acted on. I actually want the listbox item where I click the button to be acted on. How can I do this? How do I tell my `UpCommandExecuted()` method to act on the ListBoxItem where I clicked the Up button, not the actual `SelectedItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `CommandParameter={Binding}` to your `<Button>`. That will pass the data context of the selected item into your command through the `ICommand.Execute` method.

Otherwise, move the command properties to the a model that represents the items, rather than having a single set of commands defined at the root level. I personally prefer this approach. I like my commands to be parameterless and to always act on the view model class that contains the command.

Comment: Awesome that worked perfectly thank you thank you thank you!  Could you elaborate a little more on how to move the command properties ?

Comment: You have a view model class that has the `CheckCommand`, `UpCommand`, and `DownCommand` properties. Presumably, you also have a collection property on that view model class, and you're using that property in the `ItemsSource` of your `ListBox`. Presumably, that collection contains instances of another view model class (the one that contains the `IsChecked` property). Move the command properties from your root class to your item class. As you create each of the item instances, make sure you set the command properties for each item.

Comment: Then in your DataTemplate, just use `Command={Binding CheckCommand}` and the like. Note the greatly simplified binding expression. I find that often indicates a better VM design.